If $A, B \in B(H)$ with $0 \leq A \leq PBP$ for $B \geq 0$, then $A = PAP$
Trying to prove this lemma:
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $P \in B(H)$ be a projection.
If $A, B \in B(H)$ with $0 \leq A \leq PBP$ for $B \geq 0$, then $A = PAP$.
My first instinct is to look at
$$\|\sqrt{A}\psi\|^2 = \langle \sqrt{A}\psi, \sqrt{A}\psi\rangle = \langle A\psi, \psi\rangle \leq \langle PBP\psi, \psi\rangle = \langle BP\psi,P\psi\rangle$$
but I'm not sure what to do next or if this is even a good first step.
Hints, sources, solutions all much appreciated!

Consider the operator $T$ defined by $T(\sqrt{B}Px)=\sqrt{A}x$ and $T(x)=0$ for $x\perp {\rm Im}\,\sqrt{B}P.$ The operator is well defined and bounded (by $1$) as
$$\|\sqrt{A}x\|^2=\langle Ax,x\rangle \le \langle PBPx,x\rangle =\|\sqrt{B}Px\|^2$$ We have $\sqrt{A}=T\sqrt{B}P.$ Multiplying by $P$ on RHS gives $\sqrt{A}P=\sqrt{A},$ which implies  $AP=A.$ Moreover $PA=(AP)^*=A. $ Hence $PAP=P(AP)=PA=A.$
